# Woocommerce date field in checkout: block past days

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, datepicker

I have added a date field in the checkout page of woocommerce like this:

```
$fields['billing']['billing_delivery_date'] = array(
        'label'     => __('Delivery Date', 'woocommerce'),
        'type' => 'date',
        'placeholder'   => _x('Delivery date', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
        'id' => 'ddate',
        'required'  => true,
        'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'     => true
     );
```

But I want to block the user from selecting previous dates so I found this solution but unfortunately doesn't work. Any suggestions?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    jQuery("#ddate").datepicker({
        minDate: 0  
    });
}
</script>
```

***UPDATE***

jquery datepicker is not working probably because I am using the `date` type in the field. Is it possible to fix it without changing the type to text and loading jquery datepicker?

Comment: Is the datepicker itself loading? You need to have jQuery UI loaded. This example shows that this should work as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/2CZtV/

Comment: If still it is not working then you need to place the script using proper filter of WooCommerce. You can consider this relevant example to make datepicker working and then you can use datepicker options : https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-display-order-delivery-date-checkout/